# Labels in Dynamics AX V4

Tags: label, axapta

Does anyone knows how are managed table/columns labels in Dynamics AX V4 ?
There was .ald files AX2009, I found .ktd files but the content doesn't look like labels.
Thanks

Best regards

Comment: Going from my memory of the 17 year old AX 4.0, I *think* there should still be an `*.ald` file somewhere on disk as well as `.alb`, `ali`, `alc`, `alt` file. See http://santoshkmrsingh.blogspot.com/2010/05/dynamics-ax-application-file-types.html